# Powershell script for service startups pulling from another file

Tags: powershell, service

I am trying to implement a powershell script and really need some assistance as I don't really know where to go with this.

Basically I have a file that contains the below:

```
Service1 , 0
Service2 , 150
Service3 , 0
Service4 , 210
```

Service1/2/3/4 indicates the service name, and the number represents the number of seconds delay after the service startup.

So service1 gets started, then a 0 second delay. Then service2 gets started, then a 150 second delay, then service3 gets started, then a 0 second delay. And so on.

Has anyone created a powershell script like this before or know of a way to pull this information into a Start-Service script via powershell?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file format of the csv file is like you provided, you can use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3), add in some headers with the `-Header` parameter, and use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3) to loop through the values and pipe those to commands accordingly to do what you prefer.

### PowerShell

```
Import-csv -Path "C:\Folder\Services.csv" -Header "service","seconds" | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Service -Name "$($_.service.trim())";
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $_.seconds;
    };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3)
- [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Start-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Start-Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Trim()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing is:

```
$services = get-content C:\temp\sample.txt 

foreach ($line in $services) {
    $serviceName = $line.Split(",")[0]
    $timeWait = $line.Split(",")[1]
    Start-Service -Name $serviceName
    Start-sleep $timeWait
    $status = (Get-Service -Name $serviceName).Status
    Write-Host "The current status of $($serviceName) is $status"

}
```